# Optimizing a Large PostGIS Query

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I currently have a large table `mivehdetailedtrajectory` (25B rows) and a small table `cell_data_tower` (400 rows) that I need to join using PostGIS. Specifically, I need to run this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(traj.*), tower.id
FROM cell_data_tower tower LEFT OUTER JOIN mivehdetailedtrajectory traj
ON ST_Contains(tower.geom, traj.location)
GROUP BY tower.id
ORDER BY tower.id;
```

It errors out angry that it can't write to disk. This seemed weird for a SELECT so I ran EXPLAIN:
NOTICE:  gserialized_gist_joinsel: jointype 1 not supported

```
                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=28905094882.25..28905094883.25 rows=400 width=120)
   Sort Key: tower.id
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=28905094860.96..28905094864.96 rows=400 width=120)
         ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..28904927894.80 rows=33393232 width=120)
               Join Filter: ((tower.geom && traj.location) AND _st_contains(tower.geom, traj.location))
               ->  Seq Scan on cell_data_tower tower  (cost=0.00..52.00 rows=400 width=153)
               ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..15839886.96 rows=250449264 width=164)
                     ->  Seq Scan on mivehdetailedtrajectory traj  (cost=0.00..8717735.64 rows=250449264 width=164)
```

I don't understand why postgres thinks it should materialize the inner table. Also, I don't understand the plan in general to be honest. Seems like it should keep the cell_data_tower table in memory and iterate over the mivehdetailedtrajectory table. Any thoughts on how I can optimize this to (a) run, (b) do so in a reasonable amount of time. Specifically, it seems like this should be do-able in less than 1 day.

Edit: Postgres version 9.3

Comment: Please add version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: Possibly a daft question, but you do have a spatial index on mivehdetailedtrajectory? In this kind of query, you don't really need to write left outer join, as essentially you are doing a full join anyway, but restricting the results via a "spatial" join. If you replace the left outer join by a comma, you might get a different plan.

Comment: I have had similar issues with running out of disk space with hash joins. You can try setting enable_hashagg=off and/or enable_hashjoin=off. This may appear to make the query plan worse (it does), but it will switch to using a nested loop join, which while slower, will not chew up disk space. Ultimately, if you don't have a spatial index, then you are doing a double loop anyway, and just checking ST_Contains every time. I took the liberty of adding tower.id to your select, as Jakub pointed out.

Comment: I do have a spatial index on mivehdetailedtrajectory. The issue seems to be with 25B rows, nothing is reasonable. Maybe I need to start looking into something designed more appropriately for the scale of data I am working with.

Comment: @SteveY. Yes, 25bn is pretty large for a Postgres query. Are your cell_data_tower geometries essentially circles? Because, if so, it would be easy to rewrite the contains as a simple euclidean distance calculation, which would make this very amenable to map-reduce, at which point you could start thinking about Hadoop (or something similar).

Comment: They are voronoi cells, so not quite. Solution so far has been to only take small timeslices. I need to start looking into what feasibly my options are as far as hadoop or spark. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Queries that need a lot of memory are those rare places where correlated subqueries perform better (`LATERAL JOIN` should work too but those are beyond me). Also please note you didn't select tower.id so your result wouldn't be too useful.

```
SELECT tower.id, (SELECT COUNT(traj.*) 
                  FROM mivehdetailedtrajectory traj
                  WHERE ST_Contains(tower.geom, traj.location))
FROM cell_data_tower tower
ORDER BY tower.id;
```

Try running it with `LIMIT 1` first. The total runtime should be the runtime for one tower * number of towers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a db so big like you, only 80M. But in my case i create a LinkID field to know where is each geom, and calculate which one is the closest LinkID when i insert a new record.

When i found out a single LinkID take 30ms and doing that 80M times would take 27 days i went from pre calculate those values.

Also i don't keep all the records, i only keep a month at any time.